# Excel - Inserting cell value in formula column name

Tags: excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function, worksheet

I have two sheets, in first sheet the linked references value are there in columnA which has random values like 7000, 231, 799 etc

I want to insert all those linked values from Sheet2 into column in sheet1,

so those values are accessible with these codes, for example if references values are 7000, 231,799 then

i can access the values from sheet to with this formula

```
=sheet2!B7000

=sheet2!B231

=sheet2!B799
```

so I am directly trying to put the value in formula like this

```
=sheet2!B<value of A1>
=sheet2!B<value of A2>
=sheet2!B<value of A3>
```

i tried so many things which gives me error with `#NAME?`

please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INDIRECT

```
=INDIRECT("sheet2!b"&A1)
```

but I prefer to use INDEX because INDIRECT is volatile and gives you certain problems like always having to save the workbook whenever you close it

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`=INDIRECT ("sheet2!B"&sheet2!A1)`